# CSV file not recognized by WEKA

Tags: csv, data-mining, weka

I am trying to upload my data set into WEKA as a CSV file which I believe should work but the error I get is:

File 'data.csv' not recognized as an 'CSV data files' file.
Reason:
wrong number of values. Read 3, expected 13, read Token[EOL], line 118 Problem encountered on line: 118

When looking at the CSV file line 118 looks no different from the rest of the rows so I'm confused as to how to move on. The converter comes up as an option [converter gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5yVw.png)

But I am not sure how to use it to make the CSV file work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I resolved the issue by removing the ' character which was used in the name of some attributes and was ultimately causing the problem. I'm going to leave the question posted in case any else runs into the same problem

Comment: The single quote is used by Weka for quoting strings and must be escaped with \. If you want a more mainstream CSV support, have a look at the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) (unofficial) package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.